# simple javascript substitute cipher

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to cipher a result of a sum into a base64 code.

```js
var map = {
  1: 'dG',
  2: 'h2, 3: '
  gF,
  4: 'pz',
  5: 'V0'
};

if (map.indexOf(sum1) > -1) {
  ans = map.indexOf(sum1)
} else {
  console.log("Incorrect");
}
```

I want to match my number `(sum1)` to the index of my array and save the letters to the variable `ans`.

I am new to programming and would appreciate if anyone can help me here. If I didn't explain well enough please ask for clarification.

Comment: Your code is incorrect. You have a lot of syntax errors like missing `'` and `;`s. And where's `sum1`?

Comment: I made a snippet of the code and formatted which makes some of the syntax challenges more visible.  Note that `map` is not a very good name for a global variable.  Click the Run code snippet button to see the error message.  To create a snippet use that button when editing (or CTRL-M)

Comment: map is an object, it does not have indexOf. You just need to do `map[sum1]` to see if it exists

Comment: If these answers do not satisfy, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indexOf method is for arrays/strings so that is not going to work since you have an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). You idea was right to check to see if the property exists, you just are doing it the wrong way.

The best way of checking to see if the property exists in an object is to use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

```js
var map = {
  1: 'dG',
  2: 'h2', 
  3: 'gF',
  4: 'pz',
  5: 'V0'
};

function getText (obj, key) {
  // if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
  //   return obj[key];
  // } else {
  //   return null;
  // }
  return obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ? obj[key] : null;
}

console.log(getText(map, 1));
console.log(getText(map, 5));
console.log(getText(map, 100));
```

But since you have strings, you do not have to use `hasOwnProperty`, you can just use a truthy check since strings evaluate to true

```js
var map = {
  1: 'dG',
  2: 'h2', 
  3: 'gF',
  4: 'pz',
  5: 'V0'
};

function getText (obj, key) {
  // if (obj[key]) {
  //   return obj[key];
  // } else {
  //   return null;
  // }
  return obj[key] ? obj[key] : null;
}

console.log(getText(map, 1));
console.log(getText(map, 5));
console.log(getText(map, 100));
```

Or just use an array and not an object to hold your strings. The thing with arrays is the first index is ZERO so all the indexes would shift down one. So to make the 1 in your object match 1 in the array you have to put something in index 0.

```js
var map = [null, 'dG', 'h2', 'gF', 'pz', 'V0'];

function getText (obj, key) {
  // if (obj[key]) {
  //   return obj[key];
  // } else {
  //   return null;
  // }
  return obj[key] ? obj[key] : null;
}

console.log(getText(map, 1));
console.log(getText(map, 5));
console.log(getText(map, 100));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The first code snippet is just what I was looking for. I was not aware of the conditional operator but wanted to do something like this example.

Sorry for my messy question by the way!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to augment given your comment in your question.  Note that NONE of this has anything to do with a cipher...I will leave that to you to refactor in.

- Fixed syntax in your object (it IS an object)
- added ways to get both the keys and values of your object given its simple layout
- use the values of your object obtained from the object as an array (`values`)
- created a function passing in those values and one I wanted to look for
- returned an object with some fun properties to show how to do that

```js
var myObject = {
  1: 'dG',
  2: 'h2',
  3: 'gF',
  4: 'pz',
  5: 'V0'
};

function doThing(myvalues, sum1) {
  var ans = {
    checked: sum1,
    exists: false,
    index: -1
  };
  var stuffindex = myvalues.indexOf(sum1);
  var stuffExists = (stuffindex > -1);
  ans.exists = stuffExists;
  ans.index = stuffindex;
  //  console.log(ans);

  return ans;
}
var keys = Object.keys(myObject);
console.log(keys);
var values = Object.values(myObject);
console.log(values);
console.log(doThing(values, 'pz'));
var checkfor = 'gF';
console.log("Compare:", checkfor == "gf");
console.log(checkfor, " exists? ", doThing(values, checkfor).exists);
console.log('gf', " exists? ", doThing(values, 'gf').exists);
```